# На каком уровне tcp/ip указывается тип данных?

Tags: linux, http, tcp, протоколы, netcat

Допустим я передают данные через netcat, wiki говорит что он работает через протокол tcp, т.е. сверху ничего нет ftp/http и т.п.?
Т.е. отправляются и принимаются байты.
В какой момент и где записано что я передают именно текст?
Или netcat все входящие байты по умолчанию переводит в текст?

Comment: Ни на каком, передаются только байты

Comment: Ну что именно вы передаете, можно анализировать. Если вы шифруете данные, хотя бы банально SSL, то никто не узнает что это был текст или не текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у tcp/ip нет уровней. Оно само "на уровне" (Ip на 3, tcp/upd - на 4 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI ). На 3 и 4 уровнях тип данных не записывается. Просто Wireshark узнает протокол (например, по номеру порта) и декодирует по записанным правилам, но это уже 5, 6 и 7 уровень OSI.

netcat передает то, что в него отправят. Будет текст - будет текст, картинка - картинка, но в любом случае это просто последовательность байт.

Wireshark для неизвестных протоколов показывает как бинарное отображение, так и текстовое. И тут срабатывает простая штука - текстовое представление текстовых данных выглядит очень естественно:)

Comment: "netcat передает то, что в него отправят. Будет текст - будет текст, картинка - картинка, но в любом случае это просто последовательность байт." вот этот момент не до конца понимаю. Я открываю в консоле netcat и получаю данные, он отображает текст т.е. он взял последовательность бит и перевел ее в текст причем возможно даже переводил по какой то кодировке.... как он понял что надо перевести в текст?

Comment: неткат просто копирует байты в "устройство вывода" (консоль). А консоль умеет это отображать. Если кодировка совпала, то все ок.  Никто специально биты не переводил в символы.

Comment: т.е. консоль уже как бы на уровне приложений и оно соответственно уже интерпретирует байты как хочет?

Comment: где то так. вполне можно с одной стороны послать так называемые esc-коды и с другой стороны получить разукрашенный текст (если эмулятор терминала или другая программа, которая отображает текст их понимает)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ простой - нигде не записан тип данных.

Для операционной системы и файловой системы на том уровне, на котором происходит приём и сохранение байтов - тип данных не имеет значения.

Дальше, вопрос интерпретации - так же, как cat показывает текст, netcat тоже показывает текст.

Технически можно заставтить и ту, и другую программу вывести на экран бинарный файл. Будет непонятно, но весело.

Comment: т.к. конкретная программа например netcat просто по умолчанию получает байти и переводит их в текст?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов ничего не переводит. Берёт байты и выводит их куда сказали.